# passing layout_weight reference from dimensions (dimens)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I need to set different layout weights for different screen size devices and I want to pass the values from the dimens file, the problem is that the reference from the dimens file keeps throwing errors

```
error: Error: Integer types not allowed (at 'progress_widget_item3_weight' with value '9').
```

or

```
error: Error: Float types not allowed (at 'progress_widget_item3_weight' with value '9.1').
```

---

```
<dimen name="progress_widget_item3_weight">9</dimen>
```

How do I pass the value from the dimens file for the layout_weight ? Thank you

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Instead of dimensions you can use [integer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Integer) to declare and reference integers.

Example declaration in integers.xml:

```
<resources>
    <integer name="left">1</integer>
    <integer name="right">2</integer>
</resources>
```

Example reference in layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/left" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="@integer/right" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Note that using @integer values for layout_weight (which is specified to accept `float` values) will lead to `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid float` errors on certain devices such as the LG Optimus L1 / L3, Samsung Galaxy Y / Neo and Blackberry Q10.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can do that. The documentation in the xml file says just `float`(no `dimension`) unlike the `layout_width` for example where you have `dimension`.

You could just use a hardcoded `float` value in the various screen dependent layouts.